# Cannot able to run a docker image on Linux Machine for dot net core 2.1 application which is using MySQL db with Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

Following exception is being thrown when .net core 2.1 API application's docker image is executed(run) on Linux machine

I am using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql to use MySQL Database

When I build and run the api image on windows machine it is running fine, but when I tried to run the same image on linux, following exception is being thrown.

It is the same case when I build and run the image on linux machine.

Not sure what is going wrong.

> > Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004.
> >         An error occurred using the connection to database '' on server ''.
> >         MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Connect Timeout expired. ---
> >         System.ObjectDisposedException: Safe handle has been closed
> >         at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.DangerousAddRef(Boolean& 
> >         success)
> >         at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.SafeHandleAddRef(SafeHandle pHandle, 
> >         Boolean& success)
> >         Interop.Sys.TryChangeSocketEventRegistration(IntPtr port, SafeHandle socket, 
> >         SocketEvents currentEvents, SocketEvents newEvents, IntPtr data)

Looking forward for expert help and highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The container/server running MySQL Server is not accessible from your Docker container running your application. As a result, your application is timing out (“Connect Timeout expired”) when attempting to open a database connection.

Make sure your network setup allows your web server to contact the DB server on port 3306.

Comment: Yeah, It got solved!! Actually Security group was different for EC2 and RDS instances. Anyways thanks!!